# c# Extension methods - design patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, extension-methods

I would like to know if C# extension method is based on any existing design pattern.

Comment: Don't over use extension methods, see this entry Eric Lipperts blog "foreach V's ForEach" http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A design pattern is simply a well known paradigm, i.e. "when you want to achieve X, do Y". A well known paradigm in object-oriented languages such as C# is "when you want to act on the state of an object, call a method on an instance of it".

However, before extension methods were created, you could not call your own method on an instance of an object that you could not add an implementation to (e.g. interfaces because they cannot have implementations, or library classes because they are already compiled). Extension methods fill this gap by allowing you to make methods that *appear* to be callable on instances of objects, while being defined externally to the implementation of the object.

So yes, arguably extension methods are based on this very simple design pattern, of making methods that act on the state of an object appear to be callable from an instance of it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be similar to a Decorator pattern but with different structure?

Answer (score 8):

The extension methods can be thought as a replacement of the [Visitor Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx). It is also proposed that they can be used as [Adapters](http://www.geekscafe.net/post/C-30-Extension-Methods-As-Adapters.aspx).

In general languages evolve to make the need of design patterns less necessary. There is a quote for example that Lisp doesn't need design patterns, because everything is built in the language. So the right question will be, what design patterns do extension methods replace?

Comment: More accurately, (good) languages tend to evolve to streamline the use of popular design patterns. Also note that you can't ever get away from using design patterns, every design is a design pattern of some sort, the language of design patterns is just a way to formalize this idea and promote the usage of certain well-known and tested patterns (in the same way that an arch or a buttress is a well-known design pattern in architecture).

Answer (score 5):

No. It's just a language feature.

Comment: It can be both. For instance, delegates are a C# language feature that enables the Publisher-Subscriber pattern.

Answer (score 2):

They are not based on an existing design pattern. When this 'feature' was first introduced in Delphi, under the name ['class helpers'](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphifornet/a/classhelpers.htm),  Borland even warned users away from them. [They were considered a bit of a hack](http://davidglassborow.blogspot.com/2006/05/class-helpers-good-or-bad.html), but now the dust has settled they have found a place of their own.

Like everything else, use when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The closest canonical design patterns is probably the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not, because they are only syntactic sugar.

Comment: well strictly speaking extension methods are _not_ suntactic sugar. But your ability to call them with the same syntax as instance methods is.

Comment: If you don't believe me, you can simply try to find in google this phrase: "extension methods is syntactic sugar" and you can find hundreds links that prove my opinion.

Comment: Rune, without this ability extension methods are just regular static methods. "Your ability to call them with the same syntax as instance methods" *is* the only feature of extension methods, and as you said yourself, this feature is syntactic sugar.

Comment: What would be the "sour" syntax of an extension if I would like to implement one myself?

Answer (score 1):

No, but extension methods are excellent for implementing certain GoF design patterns (e.g., Prototype).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use C# extension methods if you want to implement certain design patterns. For example simulate mixins in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't label Extension Methods as any of the common design patterns, but it can be used to implement patterns like, Decorator and Adapter etc..

Answer (score 0):

The best matching design pattern to extension method is Facade pattern.
My Reason: We usually use extension methods not to introduce a new functionality beyond the target class responsibility, but simplifying using existing target class usage.
Because simplifying the target class usage is the Facade pattern concern, extension methods can alternatively be implemented using the Facade pattern.
There are some problems in extending and unit testing extension methods. So I think implementing Facade pattern is a better approach against using extension methods.
However it is possible to implement some extension methods that wrap the facade interface in order to provide a coding facility for client codes.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer to explain why?