# 'Inject' implementation into class using extension methods and thereby implementing interface?

Tags: .net, oop, extension-methods

Is it possible to 'inject' code into a class (by referencing a namespace containing extension methods) and thereby simulating base class implementation for some interface? Or is this considered bad practice (even if it is not possible)?

```
Imports MyApp.Extensions

Class SomeClass : Inherits System.SomeBaseClass : Implements MyApp.IAppInterface

End Class

Public Interface IAppInterface
    Sub InterfaceMethod()
End Interface


Namespace MyApp.Extensions
    Public Module SomeClassExtensions
        Public Sub InterfaceMethod(ByVal someClass as MyApp.SomeClass)
            //Implementation
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: No, it's not possible to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is, how would your `SomeClassExtensions.InterfaceMethod` carry out the implementation?  i.e.  What properties/methods would be defined in `IAppInterface` such that there is enough data/behavior for you to implement it in the extension method?  I think you'll find that the interface *must* have a certain "base" set of methods in order for it to be meaningful.

On top of that, people often define *other* methods on the interface to make it more conveninent for the caller -- methods that are really just compositions of the "base" set of interface methods.  These convenience methods are an excellent candidate to be *removed* from the interface, and wholly defined via extension methods.  This relieves the burden on implementors of your interface from having to implement these convenience methods (convenience methods that are usually coded the same way regardless of implementation), while still allowing your callers to enjoy the benefit of being able to invoke them.

Comment: So this is actually a non-situation?

Comment: I'm saying that in relation to your question -- simply remove those methods that you want to implement as extension methods from the interface.  You cannot in fact *literally* implement interface methods via extension methods.

Comment: Technically ok... but conceptually?

Comment: Yes, see for example`IEnumerable` and the extension methods in `Enumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what extension methods are. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182826/c-extension-methods-design-patterns) is a question about design patterns related to extension methods. The ontology of an extension method is that they "attach" actions to an object rather than the usual "is a" relationship. You can't implement interface methods with them because any object that an extension method is being attached to is non-abstract (you instantiated it already, right?) so there fore this would cause a compile error.